# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith') when connect to Upstash with next.js 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, redis

I'm trying to connect to upstash's redis with the following code.
But I get an error.

What's the problem

【code】

```
import { Redis } from "@upstash/redis";

const redis = new Redis({
  url: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_URL,
  token: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_TOKEN
});
```

【error】

```
- error node_modules\@upstash\redis\esm\platforms\nodejs.js (27:36) @ startsWith
- error Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')      
    at new Redis (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@upstash/redis/esm/platforms/nodejs.js:30:37)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/upstash/page.tsx:10:15)
    at (rsc)/./app/upstash/page.tsx (C:\SourceCode\nextjs\.next\server\app\upstash\page.js:975:1)
    at Function.__webpack_require__ (C:\SourceCode\nextjs\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async collectGenerateParams (C:\SourceCode\nextjs\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:828:17) {
  digest: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely your `process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_URL` or `process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_TOKEN` are `undefined` (or both!). You can `console.log` them to ensure they are not undefined before trying to initialize Redis.

That was the fix [for this identical issue in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/upstash/upstash-redis/issues/339), and a quick scan of [the source code](https://github.com/upstash/upstash-redis/blob/9b75ea104a3ebdcee8ce0360302782200938999c/platforms/nodejs.ts#L100-L110) shows that the only usage of `startWith` is directly following your URL or token:

```
if (
  configOrRequester.url.startsWith(" ") ||
)
...
if (
  configOrRequester.token.startsWith(" ") ||
)
```

Make sure to read [NextJS documentation around environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables) to properly consume these variables.

Comment: Thank you very much.  token was undefined .

Comment: Awesome! If that was helpful, please accept the answer so others can find the information more easily.

Comment: I did not know the function. Now change the status. Thank you